# Десятки, если не сотни (,) беженцев лишились временного пристанища. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

По какому-то правилу вроде в таких случаях не надо запятой. Но это не точно.

Comment: Да, вот бы на это правило ссылочку кто-то нашел. В последние дни были похожие вопросы про "даже": *Благополучие тысяч, даже миллионов(,) людей зависит от ценностей, навыков, умений....*

Comment: Розенталь: "Присоединительная конструкция может не выделяться с двух сторон запятыми, а только отделяться запятой от предшествующей части предложения, если эта конструкция тесно связана по смыслу с последующей частью, от которой в произношении не отделяется паузой, например: Поздно теперь, да и не к чему возвращаться к этому вопросу". "Если не сотни" -- имеет  присоединительное значение и тесно связано с последующей частью: по смыслу и грамматически вместе с последующим словом образует единое неделимое количественно-именное сочетание  "сотни беженцев" и выступает как подлежащее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Практически все дружно пишут с одной запятой:

**Десятки, если не сотн**и родных лиц вспыхнули немыслимой радостью. [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E4%E5%F1%FF%F2%EA%E8+%E5%F1%EB%E8+%ED%E5+%F1%EE%F2%ED%E8

2) Очень редко: **Десятки, если не сотни,** людей попали в лагеря по обвинению в заговоре, во главе которого стояли Тихонов и Фадеев. [Надежда Мандельштам. Воспоминания (1960-1970)]

3) Сравнить: Сейчас выявлены многие **десятки, даже сотни** явлений, предшествующих землетрясениям.  Оформление **по образцу однородных членов**.